# Question about trigger on FNIRSI oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I am new on oscilloscopes.

I bought a FNIRSI PRO DSO.  To test it I tried sending ASCII characters on an Arduino UART with the probe connected to TX and GND.  I put the command 'Serial.print("hello world")' in the loop function. I am able to see all the character's waveforms in the whole screen but they seem too crushed in the screen to analyse it.

Suppose that I need to analyze the last character (d) of the phrase. I can't find a way to zoom in on the 'd' character waveform (with all the letters.) Is there is some way to tell the trigger start cursor to start at the 'd' letter or some kind of trick?

Comment: Can you post a link to the manual? It seems the waveform file manager / details views is what you need, combined with the normal trigger mode for digital signals.

Comment: Does it not have the ability to zoom and scroll the screen after capturing a signal? Or to move the trigger to the left of the screen?